# NestJS - Increase response timeout for particular http endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs

I just started to learn about NestJS and I am wondering how could I manipulate response timeout for particular endpoints?

I could do it on a server level like:

```
  const server = await app.listen(...);
  server.setTimeout(1800000)
```

or on endpoint, which looks bad:

```
  @Post('/test')
  public async import(...props, @Res() res: Response): Promise<string> {
    res.setTimeout(1800000)
  }
```

But how could I do that on controller or method level?
I have tried to increase timeout on endpoint using interceptors like:

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler, RequestTimeoutException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, throwError, TimeoutError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, take, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {

    return next.handle().pipe(
      timeout(1800000),
      catchError(err => {
        if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
          return throwError(() => new RequestTimeoutException());
        }
        return throwError(() => err);
      }),
    );
  };
};
```

And applying it on endpoint like:

```
  @Post('/test')
  @UseInterceptors(TimeoutInterceptor)
  public async import(...props, @Res() res: Response): Promise<string> {
    long running code...
  }
```

Although interceptor is triggered so I am able to log something
the timeout does not seems to work at all :/

Comment: Here you set timeout for Observable, not the request itself. thats why your answer down there is working (as there you actually set the timeout  for the request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(
    private readonly reflector: Reflector,
  ) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    const timeout = this.reflector.get<number>('request-timeout', context.getHandler()) || 60000;
    response.setTimeout(timeout )

    return next.handle();
  };
}
```

```
import { applyDecorators, SetMetadata, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';

const SetTimeout = (timeout: number) => SetMetadata('request-timeout', timeout);

export function SetRequestTimeout(timeout: number = 60000) {
  return applyDecorators(
    SetTimeout(timeout),
    UseInterceptors(TimeoutInterceptor),
  );
}
```

You might have to play a bit with providers (add the interceptor to it)
But now you can use `@SetRequestTimeout()` or `@SetRequestTimeout(10000)` for convenience.

Comment: I follow you instruction but it doesn't work to me, could you please, if you have any documentation share it here, I need more details to find out what happen.

Comment: @HadiiVarposhti have You added the interceptor to providers and to exports if you want to use it outside the current module?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if someone is curious this is what I have done:

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    response.setTimeout(600000)

    return next.handle();
  };
};
```

Comment: As i dont like using @UseInterceptors(Interceptor) im writing for you some decorator that would make usage must easier

Comment: ```
import { applyDecorators, SetMetadata, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';


const SetTimeout = (timeout: number) => SetMetadata('request-timeout', timeout);

export function IsEventAdmin(timeout: number = 600000) {
  return applyDecorators(
    SetTimeout(timeout),
    UseInterceptors(TimeoutInterceptor),
  );
}
``` (you need to import the interceptor into it)

Comment: grr - i will put i in answer as this is totally unformatted